# SQL select query where column LIKE

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table with products in domain name, I need to be able to select the correct product based on domain name matching.

For example, if the domain is `google.co.uk` it should return the product that is `Domain Name Purchase (.co.uk)` however if the domain is `google.uk` it should be `Domain Name Purchase (.uk)`

How can I make sure I select the correct product when they are similar?

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE 'google.co.uk' like CONCAT(product, '%')
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE product LIKE '%google.co.uk%'
```

The second query works fine. However if the query is searching for a match with `.uk`, it will also return products matching `.co.uk`.

Comment: Can you give a strict definition of "*domain*"?

Comment: well, it will be a domain name

Comment: Tabular representation of sample data and desired output would be more helpful.

Comment: Assume that we never heard of Internet. We just know what strings of characters are.

Comment: so, it would be a string along with something like .co.uk, .uk, .com, .uk.com and many more

Comment: @PM 77-1 is that okay?

Comment: No, it's obviously too vague.

Comment: For example, what is the domain of `tv.tv.tv` ?

Comment: sorry, im not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you are trying to get two separate result sets with string look up with `co.uk` and `.uk` respectively.

```
SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE product LIKE '%.co.uk%'
```

should give you result matching `.co.uk`

```
SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE product LIKE '%.uk%' and product NOT LIKE '%.co.uk%'
```

would give you result matching `.uk` only, with `.co.uk` excluded.

Comment: correct, however its not always going to be .co.uk and .uk as there are many others. so its going to be based on the full domain name itself (e.g. domain1.com / domain-test.org / domain-123.me.uk) and many more

Comment: For this you need to set up a more specific rule for string matching. For example whether it is the product always with url extension and country `.com` and `.com.xx`. Only with the knowledge on all possible value in the field you can set up a robust rule for the query.

Comment: how about if i add an extra column to my products table which contains the domain TLD (.com/.co.uk etc) and do the lookup on that column?

Comment: It would be the best if you can break it down into `url extension` and `country extension`

Answer (score 0):

The one suggestion is to careful on doing this and think on your dB design in future

A fully qualified domain name could consist of any text and in any format given certain guidelines you may want to consider splitting up name vs the qualifier e.g. co.uk into separate fields

Comment: ok so if i split the domain in the database, how would i then search my products table?

Comment: Hi Charlie, as per comment from ydoow, they've hit the nail on the head per my comment. A URL is difficult item to do this and you ideally need to split it out per my comment. When I say split I essentially mean into different columns in your database structure going forward.